# How can I get quake2 running on ubuntu without cd?

Tags: 15.04

When I launch `quake 2` on my Ubuntu 15.04 I get the following error:

> Missing data; see /usr/share/doc/quake2/README.DEBIAN

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

"Quake2 for debian" which is freely downloadable is just the game engine, you need the game data (found on game disk) as well to play Quake2.

Read that readme.debian to find information.

Comment: Read the top. Without CD

Comment: You want instructions for pirating a game. No.

Comment: Not exactly. If there is a demo or something that's what i'm looking for.  I have the demo, how do I build the data? When I launch it says, well, read the post